# ord/char question

Tags: php, encoding

I have text that has ord elements in it such as:

```
Ya marc&#1091; medianoche
```

what converts that text into proper text?

Comment: in php .  some function hopefully

Answer (score 4):

Because its not just a "ord", but its a html-entity written as utf-codepoint you can use `html_entity_decode()`

```
var_dump(html_entity_decode("Ya marc&#1091; medianoche", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"));
```